# "npm i -g gulp" install error

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm trying to install this: npm i -g gulp

But the output are these lines:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 16.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "gulp"
npm ERR! node v7.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

*Just in case: when I ran **npm root -g**, I got the correct root folder: **/usr/local/lib/node_modules***

Please, how can I solve this? And install **npm i -g gulp** ??

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md

Comment: sudoless, or just go ahead and use sudo: `sudo npm install -g gulp-cli`

Comment: @Ryan it works! great thanks! I'd love to know how does it works adding "sudo" and "-cli" ... I mean, what's the difference between this line and this one: npm i -g gulp ? Thanks again.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo ; NPM recommends not using `sudo` but instead changing permissions. See: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Answer (score 0):

see the error message: `EACCES: permission denied`. Link to [fixing npm permissions](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions#fixing-npm-permissions).

for me, on a new system I'll execute the command found at the reference above:

```
 sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}
```

There is another option show at the link above for changing the directory where NPM installs packages to.